# LinkedHashSet serialization excpetion in GWT Development Mode only

Tags: java, serialization, gwt, deserialization

I have the problem that I get this SerializationException

`com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The response could not be deserialized`

`Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.util.LinkedHashSet/95640124`

but just in the Development Mode of GWT 2.7.0. If I compile the application and run it on the webserver (tomcat) it is working fine. Does anybody have an idea why this is the case?

The object which causes the exception is the following:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class MyCustomObject implements IndexedContent, IsSerializable {
    //PLACEHOLDER
}
```

I'm just receiving a list of MyCustomObject.

**Why is it not working locally in Dev Mode but compiled on the server?**

Comment: I could see that some classes in the source code of MyCustomObject are not serializable (for instance List or Set). But that would only be a problem if MyCustomObject has some non transient members of that type.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But shouldn't problems based on this fact occur the same way locally and on the webserver?

Comment: Probably not. Since in "Production-Mode" the client executes the compiled JavaScript (and JavaScript has no built in support for abstractions like Java-Interfaces). Im not sure about that but you could try to replace all non-serializable interfaces by serializable implementations of that interface and look wether the exception still occurs,

Comment: That's true. If I remove the LinkedHashSet and replace it with a HashSet it is already working. I will try to optimize it.